# Mapbox way to control label density

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using style mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9 with Mapbox GL JS API,  and I would like to reduce the density of labels.

As far as I researched, density is based on labels collision boxes.

Is there an option where I could set the density as I create the Map Javascript Object?

Or, can I increase labels' collision boxes by any means? Add some padding, for instance?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text-padding symbol layout property does this https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-padding.

It's probably easier to copy the dark style in Mapbox Studio and set this value for label layers.